# Making TeX PDFs compatible with Word 2016 importing

Tags: pandoc, msword, latex-to-word

I'm changing the focus of this question after experimenting a little further, I've left the original question in the quote at the bottom.

As the original question points out, newer versions of Word (I think from 2013 onward) support the importing of PDFs into editable form (though obviously with not 100% faithful reproduction).

However, Word doesn't seem to play nicely with PDFs I create with Tex, and it would be handy if they did so that my supervisor can proofread the doc.

**My question therefore is what the differences are or what needs to be done to a TeX PDF in order for Word to be able to open it? Or is it impossible for some other reason?**

As per the previous comments, I tried LuaLatex and XeLaTeX, but the same issues persist (see screen shots). I then thought that it might be due to the fact that on OSX, TeXShop's default encoding is Latin, but after shifting everything to UTF-8, there is still no difference - the result of `file -I doc.tex` states that the document is `ASCII`, which from my research is already a subset of `UTF8`.

The only other curiosity I've noticed, is that if I try to get Word to open the document, treating it as `ASCII`, it unchecks the box automatically, and doesn't render a preview, whereas I can select any other encoding just fine (though the preview is obviously gibberish).

There must be some subtlety here which I'm missing since [PDF2DOCx.com](http://pdf2docx.com/) is able to do a surprisingly faithful reconstruction of the whole TeX document that can be opened in Word.

#### Import process for Word

(using a PDF typeset under Unicode UTF-8 (Ascii) and exported with XeLaTeX)

[image]
[image]

---

> I realise this has been asked a million times, but I'm going round in
>   circles at the moment, and a good number of the threads are old so I'm
>   wondering if there is some more up to date information around with
>   regards to converting Tex files (typeset, not raw) or better yet, PDFs
>   in to Word 2013 or greater .docx formats?
>
> Specifically, I'm looking for commandline tools so that I can include
>   it in a workflow?
>
> So far I've tried with Pandoc, but there are issues with UTF-8
>   formatting that I can't unpick, and you cant convert from PDF.
>
> Word is capable of opening PDFs natively these days, and does a good
>   job of it usually, but it doesn't seem to be able to read my LaTeX
>   PDFs at all (if anyone has thoughts on this point too I'd be glad to
>   hear them).
>
> Despite the document being very large and complex, I've had some
>   excellent results with online converters, but I'd really not like to
>   have to use them each time if possible - thought this tells me it must
>   be doable if only they were available on the commandline.
>
> Has anyone come across and tools more recently perhaps that would fit
>   the bill?

Comment: As a starting point, try compiling with XeTeX and LuaLatex and open the resulting PDFs with Word. Font handling is different for these tools, which may lead to word having an easier time.

Comment: You could try [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) I don't know how capable it is though.

Comment: it all depends on your document and which features you use. tex4ht can compile LaTeX to `odt` which needs to be converted to `docx` using LibreOffice (Word has issue with these ODT files, because it seems that it doesn't really follow the ODT standard). It supports utf-8, math, footnotes, tables, images and other features. Try `mk4ht oolatex filename.tex`

Comment: @DCTLib the document is very large and complex at this point (a thesis) and so won't compile with XeTeX or LuaLatex without a lot of messing about with the source (unless I'm missing something - I've never used them before). @Thorbjørn, I tried `pandoc` as my question mentions, but doesn't seem to be capable of it in this instance either.

Comment: have you tried xelatex or lualatex? what error did you get?

Comment: Strangely xelatex just worked after I went to try and reproduce the error, but Word still can't open it. Could this be due to the fact that the document is currently using the default TexShop Western-Latin1 encoding? Perhaps Word expects Unicode or something? LuaLatex complains that I have a package clash for the `color` package and the `table{xcolor}` package implementation (though this compiles fine under LaTeX.

Comment: Apologies for my late reply: I have tried all settings exporting .tex to .docx - with pandoc and however had to resolve to with www.ilovepdf.com which rendered even formats quite nicely.

Comment: I had a similar experience with `pdf2doc.com`, which was what made me wonder originally why those sites could do it, but Word couldn’t manage it itself...